# Smartface 4.5 Missing Table Icon

Tags: smartface.io

Smartface 4.5 missing table icon and the filter icon.

4.4 icons  :

[image: 4.4 Icons]

4.5 icons :

[image: 4.5 Icons]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Smartface 4.5 also doesnot open it's emulator on android devices a big bug.

Comment: @ManthanShah are you use the free version? If so, you are only allowed 10 times to use usb upload.

Comment: No I am using Individual licence.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Smartface 4.5 will allow you to use any SQL Lite Manager to create/Modify your database by access the db file in our project folder.